# Is Sapphire Radeon R7 240 With Boost 1GB DDR5 compatible with Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: 17.04, gpu-driver

Is the Sapphire Radeon R7 240 With Boost 1GB DDR5 graphics card supported by Ubuntu 17.04?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a hardware compatibility question.

Answer (score 1):

The [Ubuntu RadeonDriver page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver) shows the AMD R7 240 card has been supported since version 14.04 so you should be alright. If in doubt boot using a Ubuntu live USB to check that everything works ok.